# Python. Creating feature vectors where entries are sequences of past states

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

To be specific, I have multivariant time series data, lets say

u(k) = [u_0(k), .. , u_n(k)]

I need to create new feature vectors, y(k) consisting of the original time series at time k plus l past values, that is y(k) is:

y(k) = [u(k)^T, u(k-1)^T, ... , u(k-l)^T]

where l can be any number of time steps desired. So for example if I have

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)), columns = ["u_0", "u_1", "u_2", "u_3", "u_4"])

   u_0  u_1  u_2  u_3  u_4
0    0    1    2    3    4
1    5    6    7    8    9
2   10   11   12   13   14
3   15   16   17   18   19
4   20   21   22   23   24
```

With `l = 2`, y(3) should be

```
y[3]= [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19] , [10,  11,  12,  13,  14], [5,   6,   7,   8,   9]]
```

I'm having trouble comming up with a solution that doesnt involve any `for-loops`. Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your notation... It seems convoluted to me.

Comment: It is quite a common notation, what is that you do not understand?

Comment: do you want `y` to be a dataframe, so that the column `3` should be the three lists, or could y be a factory instance that produces your desired output depending on `l` on the fly?

Comment: I´ll use y to train a machine learning algorithm, so I was thinking on y beeing an array. I dont know what a factory instance is, sorry!

Comment: You are mixing brackets and parenthesis. `y[3]` and `y(3)` Guess that's why did not understand.

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis is just normal mathematical notation but sommeone eddited the question suggesting I highlight that as code. Maybe I should change it back, would that make it clearer?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a note on it so that other readers don't think that it's python code, an assumption that is easy to make given that python is the language in question. I've updated my answer, please give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can work, assuming we want to pad with 0s when needed:

```
data_1 = data.copy()
data_2 = data.copy()
data_1.index = data_1.index+1
data_2.index = data_2.index+2
df= pd.concat([data, data_1, data_2], axis=1).fillna(0) 

X = df.apply(lambda x: np.split(x, 3), axis=1)
```

I'm leaving the Q open in case someone has a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

I came over a similar problem in my work, and since I wrote the other (poor) answer, I've learned of pandas `shift()`-method.

Given the same data as in the question:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)), 
              columns = ["u_0", "u_1", "u_2", "u_3", "u_4"])
```

that has the DataFrame:

```
# data DataFrame:
   u_0  u_1  u_2  u_3  u_4
0    0    1    2    3    4
1    5    6    7    8    9
2   10   11   12   13   14
3   15   16   17   18   19
4   20   21   22   23   24
```

Here is a function (lambda) that you can call, given a value `l` is already defined:

```
l = 2
y = lambda r: [df.shift(i).iloc[r].values.tolist() for i in range(l+1)]
```

So then the returned value of `y(3)` is:

```
[[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0],
 [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
```

Of course, if you can use numpy arrays, then the `.tolist()` is not needed, and if you can use pandas Series, then the `.values` part can be skipped too. I've used both here, as the desired output in the question was a list of lists.

This can be rewritten in various ways, of course, e.g. the `l`-value can be a parameter too, by rewriting y to:

```
y = lambda r, l: [df.shift(i).iloc[r].values.tolist() for i in range(l+1)]
```

Which the is called `y(3,2)`, if `l=2`.

Or, if preferring functions over lambdas, just make a normal one:

```
def shifted_lookback(row_i, n_lookbacks):
    return [df.shift(i).iloc[row_i].values.tolist() for i in range(n_lookbacks+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

**TL;DR**: A one-block implementation:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(...)  # Your data
 l = 2

 n_rows = df.shape[0]

 dfs = []   # views of the dataframe to concat
 for i in range(l+1):
        dfs.append(df[l-i: n_rows-i].reset_index(drop=True))

 new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)[:n_rows-l]
```

**update**: From the [answer of BS BS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48284050/1144382), to make the desired result (see comments and the question), simply add what he does:

```
new_df.apply(lambda x: np.split(x, 3), axis=1)
```

However, this adds little or nothing to what his answer does. (Except perhaps that when copying the DataFrames, they're copied in memory, whereas using slices reads the same data multiple times.)  //**update**.

**//EDIT**

Here is an example making a new DataFrame with the extended values, in this case `l=2`:

```
l = 2
pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(df[2:].values), 
        pd.DataFrame(df[1:-1].values), 
        pd.DataFrame(df[:-2].values)
    ], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Outputs

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
0  10  11  12  13  14   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4
1  15  16  17  18  19  10  11  12  13  14   5   6   7   8   9
2  20  21  22  23  24  15  16  17  18  19  10  11  12  13  14
```

I have assumed that you don't want to keep the first 2 rows, and neither the last 2 rows, as they would be filled with `NaN`-values.

**A general way for any value of l:**

A general method to generate the slices:

```
def make_slices(l):
    slices = []
    for i in range(l+1):
        slices.append((l-i, -i))
    return slices
```

or as a generator

```
def slices_generator(l):
    for i in range(l+1):
        yield l-i, -i
```

then you can make a list of DataFrames objects to pass to the `concat`-method:

```
def make_dfs(df, l):
    dfs = []
    for i_from, i_to in slices_generator(l):
        dfs.append(df[i_from:df.shape[0]-i_to].reset_index(drop=True))
    return dfs
```

And to assemble it:

```
def get_timeseries(df, l):
    return pd.concat(make_dfs(df, l), axis=1, ignore_index=True)[:df.shape[0]-l]
```

*The last bit:* `[:df.shape[0]-l]`, *is just to clip of the last rows that would otherwise be filled with `NaN`s*.

The using it:

```
get_timeseries(df, 2)
```

would produce this:

```
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   10  11  12  13  14
0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0   0   1   2   3   4
1  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   5   6   7   8   9
2  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  10  11  12  13  14
```

Comment: Sorry, but the end result is not what is being asked in OP. Maybe you can use np.split as posted on my other answer. Both answers are highly redundant then.

Comment: if I understand your question, then in my example, `y = get_timeseries(df, 2)`, and then to get the y[3] you would read the first row in y, e.g. `y.iloc[0]`, or you can use `y.T[0]`. (The 3rd row in your data is the 0'th row in my example, because as I mentioned, the first and last 2 rows are omitted due to `NaN`s. Does this help you?

Comment: I see what I did wrong now, I'm sorry, you're correct. I will fix this when I get on computer 

Comment: Honest question, why are you splitting a simple operation in so many functions? Particularly get_timeseries(df, l) seems unnecessary. Is that some sort of python etiquette or just personal style? Personally, I think your code will gain if you merged the functions in one.

Comment: Thanks for patience, I haven't figured out a better way than what you did yourself, and I've added that to my answer. Only difference is that reading slices of the original DataFrame will prevent copying of data `l` times, but unless you have a lot of data that should not be an issue.

Comment: To reply to your question on why I split my code into multiple methods, I have several reasons: when I answer questions on SO I use Jupyter Notebook to draft code and reduce the chance that I give answers that won't parse or otherwise will fail, so then I re-use parts of code in multiple cells to "keep" existing tries. Also, I think that in some cases that makes it more explicit to the reader what the code does, but that could just as easily be done with comments. Thirdly, I tend to split my code up in atomic concepts, but not as much as my answer gave impression of :)